# How do you open a CSV file in Python?

Tags: python, csv

I am still fairly new to coding however I am trying to open a CSV file in my python script to show that I can at least connect to the file and then write a new file. This is important because my final script is going to need to talk to our server and save a CSV file onto our NAS. I have attempted the following just to see if I can open a CSV file in python and nothing is working.

### First Code:

```
def CSV_Creation():
    with open('test.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    for row in csv_reader:
        print(row[0])   

CSV_Creation()
```

### Second Code:

```
def CSV_Creation():
    os.getcwd()#if there is an issue check right here for testing and debugging
    os.chdir(os.path.expanduser("~/Documents"))
    os.getcwd() #second test to determine the correct path is being used
    print (os.getcwd())
    f = open("~/Documents/'test.csv'")
    with open('test.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    for row in csv_reader:
        print(row[0])   

CSV_Creation()
```

---

Now I already have the CSV file created in the Documents folder but its still producing the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/REDACTED/Documents/Python
>   Projects/BBEditRunTemp-networktest.py", line 59, in 
>       CSV_Creation()   File "/Users/REDACTED/Documents/Python Projects/BBEditRunTemp-networktest.py", line 53, in CSV_Creation
>       f = open("Users/REDACTED/Documents/'test.csv'") FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>
> "Users/REDACTED/Documents/'test.csv'"

NOTE: ignore the REDACTED portion I just changed the user name for this instance. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ...why are there quotes around `test.csv` in `~/Documents/'test.csv'`?

Comment: check your file path it has quotes in path...that should not be there. should be  f = open("~/Documents/test.csv")

Comment: in f = open("Users/REDACTED/Documents/'test.csv'"), remove single quotes around test.csv, and this error should resolve

Comment: I have removed the quotes on the test.csv portion but it still throws the same error. The reason I put 2 different codes is because I ran it the way the trainings show for opening a CSV file but that doesn't work. So I wrote the second code thinking I needed to define the path to open the file both throw the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First code

```
def CSV_Creation():
  with open('test.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    for row in csv_reader:
      print(row)   

CSV_Creation()
```

Second Code:

```
def CSV_Creation():
  #os.getcwd()#if there is an issue check right here for testing and debugging
  os.chdir(os.path.expanduser("~/Documents"))
  #os.getcwd() #second test to determine the correct path is being used
  print (os.getcwd())
  # f = open("~/Documents/'test.csv'")
  with open('test.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    for row in csv_reader:
      print(row)
```

CSV_Creation()

Comment: Thanks this solved the issue. Taking out the f = open line took care of the issue along with some indentation adjustments it runs now thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you look at the documentation for the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-contents) module, which provides a handy example:

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('eggs.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
...     spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
...     for row in spamreader:
...         print ', '.join(row)
Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Baked Beans
Spam, Lovely Spam, Wonderful Spam
```

Applying this example to your data:

```
import csv
with open('~/Documents/test.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    for row in spamreader:
        print ', '.join(row)
```

Comment: I have removed the quotes on the test.csv portion but it still throws the same error.  The reason I put 2 different codes is because I ran it the way the trainings show for opening a CSV file but that doesn't work. So I wrote the second code thinking I needed to define the path to open the file both throw the same error.